# Django API : Variable Filter (is null)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my Django project, I have Django running as rest API and I want to filter value null based on a variable column that the user gonna choose.

For filtering by equals I did something like that :

```
field = fields[i]
value = values[i]
queryset = queryset.filter(**{field:value})
```

but if i leave value empty the query does not work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(**{f'{field}__isnull':True})
```

Comment: with double underscore

Comment: @DiegoPuente Exactly, a typo :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with:

```
field = fields[i]
value = values[i]  # can be the empty string
queryset = queryset.filter(**{field: value or None})
```

If `value` is an empty string, then its *truthiness* is `False`, and it will thus use the second operand of the `or` operator, in this case `None`. If `value` is a string with at least item, its truthiness is `True`, and thus it will use `value`.

If on the other hand you want to prevent filtering with empty strings/`None` values, you can make the filtering conditional:

```
field = fields[i]
value = values[i]  # can be the empty string
if value:
    queryset = queryset.filter(**{field: value})
```